# MSXML load url failes only on Windows 2016 server

Tags: vb6

I am trying to modify an old VB6 application so that it can be used on Windows server 2016. At the moment it works well on Windows XP and Windows 7/10.

But for WIndows Server 2016 I do not get it going. I want to grab temperature data via https://xml.buienradar.nl. In the vb6 project I make a reference to msxml6 which I installed on the Windows 2016 server.

At xmldoc.Load ("https: \ xml.buienradar.nl") I get the error: *The download of the specified resource has failed.*

Firewall is disabled. Does anyone have any idea? I do not have the idea that it goes wrong with the msxml6.dll. Why does this work with all other operating systems?

```
Set xmldoc = New DOMDocument60
xmldoc.async = False

If xmldoc.Load("https:\\xml.buienradar.nl") = False Then
    LogPrint "Load error: " & xmldoc.parseError.url & " - " &  
    xmldoc.parseError.reason
Else
    -- grab data --
End If
```

Comment: `msxml6` is already preinstalled on Win2016 Server. I just tested your snipped here and it's working fine on Win2016 Server. Make sure you can access this site from this (locked down) Win2016 Server, e.g. use `IE`, `Edge`, `curl` to test internet connectivity.

Comment: If you're getting an error from MSXML like "The download... failed" that seems to imply that the MSXML library itself is functioning ie is not an installation problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? We seem to have a very similar problem.